# Process 'command 'C:\Users\admin\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aidl.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

i have a problem in android studio:

*i changed the compile sdk version in: file - Project structure -- but without any effect*

```
**Process 'command 'C:\Users\admin\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aidl.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1**
```

how can I fix this error?

***run Build: Build Failed***

```
    org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':openCVLibrary24133:compileReleaseAidl'.
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:127)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':openCVLibrary24133:compileReleaseAidl'.
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
        at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
        at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:122)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':openCVLibrary24133:compileReleaseAidl'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
        ... 2 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\admin\Favorites\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aidl.exe with arguments {-pC:\Users\admin\Favorites\Sdk\platforms\android-25\framework.aidl -oC:\Users\admin\Documents\phimpme-android\openCVLibrary24133\build\generated\source\aidl\release -IC:\Users\admin\Documents\phimpme-android\openCVLibrary24133\src\main\aidl -IC:\Users\admin\Documents\phimpme-android\openCVLibrary24133\src\release\aidl -dC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl1391949474798133428.d C:\Users\admin\Documents\phimpme-android\openCVLibrary24133\src\main\aidl\org\opencv\engine\OpenCVEngineInterface.aidl}
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AidlCompile.doFullTaskAction(AidlCompile.java:193)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:82)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\admin\Favorites\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aidl.exe with arguments {-pC:\Users\admin\Favorites\Sdk\platforms\android-25\framework.aidl -oC:\Users\admin\Documents\phimpme-android\openCVLibrary24133\build\generated\source\aidl\release -IC:\Users\admin\Documents\phimpme-android\openCVLibrary24133\src\main\aidl -IC:\Users\admin\Documents\phimpme-android\openCVLibrary24133\src\release\aidl -dC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl1391949474798133428.d C:\Users\admin\Documents\phimpme-android\openCVLibrary24133\src\main\aidl\org\opencv\engine\OpenCVEngineInterface.aidl}
        at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:147)
        at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.SourceSearcher.search(SourceSearcher.java:76)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.compileAllAidlFiles(AndroidBuilder.java:1082)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AidlCompile.compileAllFiles(AidlCompile.java:130)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AidlCompile.doFullTaskAction(AidlCompile.java:191)
        ... 27 more
    Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\admin\Favorites\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aidl.exe with arguments {-pC:\Users\admin\Favorites\Sdk\platforms\android-25\framework.aidl -oC:\Users\admin\Documents\phimpme-android\openCVLibrary24133\build\generated\source\aidl\release -IC:\Users\admin\Documents\phimpme-android\openCVLibrary24133\src\main\aidl -IC:\Users\admin\Documents\phimpme-android\openCVLibrary24133\src\release\aidl -dC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl1391949474798133428.d C:\Users\admin\Documents\phimpme-android\openCVLibrary24133\src\main\aidl\org\opencv\engine\OpenCVEngineInterface.aidl}
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:74)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:49)
        at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.AidlProcessor.processFile(AidlProcessor.java:104)
        at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.SourceSearcher$1.call(SourceSearcher.java:96)
        at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.SourceSearcher$1.call(SourceSearcher.java:93)
    Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\admin\Favorites\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aidl.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:369)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:47)
        ... 3 more
```

**Build.Gradle** file >>>

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'jacoco-android'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.fphdo.phimpmaker"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        resConfigs "en"
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','x86'
        }
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled false
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.apache.maven/maven-artifact/pom.xml'
        exclude 'licenses/javolution.license.TXT'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.apache.maven.wagon/wagon-http-shared/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/*'
        exclude 'org/codehaus/classworlds/uberjar/boot/Bootstrapper.class'
    }

    configurations {
        compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.volley'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        disable "Instantiatable"
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        configure(options) {
            // TODO
            compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked"
            compilerArgs << "-Xlint:-rawtypes"
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/dasar/maven"
    }
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo'
    }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    maven{ url "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.box/box-android-sdk" }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //google and support
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:customtabs:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$rootProject.gmsVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:$rootProject.gmsVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:$rootProject.gmsVersion"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    //exoplayer
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.7'

    //utils
    compile 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.1.0'
    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$rootProject.butterknifeVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$rootProject.butterknifeVersion"
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:1.5.0'
    compile 'de.psdev.licensesdialog:licensesdialog:1.8.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.daksh:loglr:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile group: 'com.box', name: 'box-android-sdk', version: '4.0.8'

    //icons
    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.8.4@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.3.original@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:community-material-typeface:1.5.54.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.6.0.1@aar'

    //ui
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'uz.shift:colorpicker:0.5@aar'
    compile 'com.turingtechnologies.materialscrollbar:lib:10.0.3'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.7'
    compile 'com.github.shchurov:horizontalwheelview:0.9.5'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'

    //twitter
    compile "com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:$rootProject.twitterVersion"
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-media-support-3.0.5.jar')

    //facebook
    compile "com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:$rootProject.stethoVersion"
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'

    //cloud rail
    compile 'com.cloudrail:cloudrail-si-android:2.20.1'

    //next cloud
    compile "com.github.nextcloud:android-library:$rootProject.nextCloudVersion"

    //leak canary
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'

    //flickr
    compile files('libs/flickrj-android-2.1.0.jar')

    //tumblr
    compile ('com.tumblr:jumblr:0.0.11'){
        exclude module:'scribe'
    }

    //realm
    compile 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.0.0'

    //metadataextractor
    compile 'com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.9.1'

    //tests
    testCompile "junit:junit:$rootProject.junitVersion"
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'

    //opencv
    compile project(':openCVLibrary24133')

    //pdk
    compile project(':pdk')

    //photoview
    compile project(':photoview')

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.dicedmelon.gradle:jacoco-android:0.1.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'jacoco-android'


[https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuOO8.jpg][1]
```

***- Build.Gradle :errors >>>>***

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuOO8.jpg

+

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OclNE.jpg

how can I fix this error?**

**Process 'command 'C:\Users\admin\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aidl.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1**